# Remove keys with empty strings in all the dictionaries in a list (essentially remove empty columns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

- This is a list of dictionary
- Some keys on a dictionary (as in the element of a list) may contain missing values
- I want to remove the keys entirely from all the dictionaries in the list, **if** they have empty strings as value which is in every dictionary element of the list. (see the code for a better explanation)
- The key-value structure of the dictionary element remains the same
- Preferably in a opitimized way possible without using third party libraries. I have a working solution and it is very greedy.

#### Code example

```py
dict_data = [
  {"a": "lorem", "b": "ipsum", "c": ""},
  {"a": "lorem2", "b": "ipsum1", "c": ""},
  {"a": "", "b": "ipsum3", "c": ""},
  {"a": "lore3", "b": "", "c": ""}
]
```

In this situation, I want to remove, the key `"c"` from all the dictionaries, as that key has no value (empty string) in each dictionary of the list. If you convert this to a table structure this will represent a column with no values.

#### Expected Result

The result will look something like this:

```py
dict_data = [
  {"a": "lorem", "b": "ipsum"},
  {"a": "lorem2", "b": "ipsum1"},
  {"a": "", "b": "ipsum3"},
  {"a": "lore3", "b": ""}
]
```

Only the `"c"` key across all the dictionary in the list is removed.

#### What I tried till now:

Works but not satisfied with the amount of `for loops`.

```py
# will contain {"key_with_mssing_values": "number_of_rows_that_has_missing_values_for_this_key"}
missing_values_dict = {}

for row in dict_data:
    for key, value in row.items():
        if not value:
            if key in missing_values_dict:
                missing_values_dict[key] +=1
            else:
                missing_values_dict[key] = 1

# missing_values_dict ==> {'c': 4, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}

for key, value in missing_values_dict.items():
    # if the value is equal to the length of the list
    # it means it is missing values on all the rows/dictionaries
    if value == len(dict_data):
        [row.pop(key, None) for row in dict_data]

# dict_data
## [{'a': 'lorem', 'b': 'ipsum'}, {'a': 'lorem2', 'b': 'ipsum1'}, {'a': '', 'b': 'ipsum3'}, {'a': 'lore3', 'b': ''}]
```

I appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check **ALL** rows are empty, you don't need to iterate all elements in all rows. Just ones that were empty previously.

```
empty = set(dict_data[0].keys())
for d in dict_data:
    for k in empty.copy():
        if d[k] != "":
            empty -= {k}

for k in empty:
    for d in dict_data:
        d.pop(k, None)
        
print(dict_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 'lorem', 'b': 'ipsum'},
 {'a': 'lorem2', 'b': 'ipsum1'},
 {'a': '', 'b': 'ipsum3'},
 {'a': 'lore3', 'b': ''}]
```

Comment: That is a really smart solution. Thanks!